# Invariance group of Morse charts

Tags: invariant-theory, morse-theory

Suppose I have a smooth function $\varphi$ that vanishes at $p$ and has a positive definite Hessian at that point (suppose that we are on a smooth manifold of dimension $M$). Then the Morse lemma tells us that we can find a chart $x$ (let us call it Morse chart) such that
$$ \varphi = (x^1)^2 + \dots + (x^n)^2 = \langle x, x \rangle.$$
What is the transformation group of Morse charts?

To be more precise, I am looking for a group that acts freely and transitively on the set of Morse charts.

Obviously, the group $O(n)$ acting on the set of Morse charts via $(Q, x) \mapsto Q\cdot x$ is a subgroup of this group. But are there more such transformations?

Answer (score 6):

Aren't you looking for the group of diffeomorphisms $f$ satisfying $\varphi \circ f= \varphi$?

The only difficulty that I can see is if the subset of $\mathbb R^n$ on which the chart is defined can vary. In that case, I do not think you will get a free transitive action that is natural in any way. Instead, there will be a groupoid action, with the morphisms $U \to V$ being diffeomorphisms $f: U \to V$ preserving $\varphi \circ f=\varphi$.

Comment: Hi Will (and Kofi).  (1.)  It seems to me that one can work with the set of *germs* of charts near p, and the group of *germs* of diffeomorphisms fixing p.  Then the action is well-defined and free and transitive.

Comment: (2.)  Yes, we're interested in the diffeomorphisms satisfying $\varphi \circ f = \varphi$.  Such a diffeo $f$ has the property that, on each level set $\{x:|x|^2=r\}$, $f$ restricts to a diffeo of the level set.  Moreover the possible $f$ are basically characterized by this property.  Think of $f$ as a (germ of a) 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms of the $(n-1)$-sphere, modulo some boundary conditions  (tending to the identity near 0) to ensure smoothness at $p$.

Comment: If you take the derivatives at the origin you get three power series that formally satisfy the equation $f^2+g^2+h^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$. There are lots of power series that formally satisfy this equation, as you can see by building it up step by step: degree $1$ terms, then degree $2$, then degree $3$, etc. It seems to me that many of them should have positive radius of convergence but I haven't checked. If some of them do have positive radius of convergence that gets you a lot of germs that aren't $O(n)$.

Comment: But it's not clear at all to me what should be the boundary conditions near $0$.

Comment: @WillSawin  a  precise example  of  convergence  of  the power seris:Assume  that $\gamma$ is  an  analytic  curve  in $O(n)$ then define the map G with $G(X)= \gamma({|X|^2})X $ is  an  analytic diffeomorphism satisfies $|G(X)|=|X|$.

Comment: @Matthias I think that  the  group  of  Local diffeomorphism around the origin can be  very  Large. But  what  about  the  following  modification:

Comment: @Matthias  For a compact manifold $M$ is there a finite dimensional group $G$ of diffeomorphisms of $M$ such that for every Morse function $\phi :M \to \mathbb{R}$ there is a non trivial element $f\in G$ such that $\phi \circ f=\phi$? I admit that this a completely different question but is motivated by your question.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Given that it's been almost 5 years since the question was first asked, if you're interested in that question it might make sense to ask it again. However I think the answer is almost certainly no, as $\phi \circ f= \phi$ can be written as infinitely many equations and hence the set where it is satisfied should have infinite codimension.